# synchronization depending on a static field?

Tags: java, static, synchronization

I am using a utility class called XMLUnit that has a static property to ignore white spaces. I use it in a test, shown below:

```
    XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
    DetailedDiff detailedDiff = new DetailedDiff(XMLUnit.compareXML(expected, actual));

    detailedDiff.overrideElementQualifier(new ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier());
    List<Difference> allDifferences = detailedDiff.getAllDifferences();
```

But some tests don't ignore the whitespaces and I think our Jenkins runs them in parallel. What is the best way of making sure I don't impact the other tests? Could I synchronize on the XMLUnit class like below?

```
    synchronized (XMLUnit.class) {
        XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
        DetailedDiff detailedDiff = new DetailedDiff(XMLUnit.compareXML(expected, actual));

        detailedDiff.overrideElementQualifier(new ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier());
        List<Difference> allDifferences = detailedDiff.getAllDifferences();
        XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(false);
    }
```

Also, if I have multiple maven modules that are being build in parallel on jenkins, and they all use this class what will the behavior be? Will each module have it's own instance of XMLUnit.class?

Comment: I don't think the issue is in synchronization. You just need to be sure ` XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);` is run before your tests - e.g. place it in `@Before` JUnit annotation

Comment: I suspect you may have to split up your tests into those that can be run in parallel and those that cannot.  The tests relying on this property cannot be run in parallel if some need it one way, and others need it the other way.  Synchronization may help you, but depending on the test duration you may be holding a lock for too long and cause tests to timeout.

Comment: Good point but it is used in cucumber steps, not in Junit

Answer (score 0):

Synchronizing class can work as long as there is nothing relying in that xml stuff outside a synchronized class block (with this i mean that is not enough to synchronize the flag true/false statement, but instead everything relying on it; the code you pasted seemed right, but you are the one to know if there is anything more relying on that flag outside the synch).

If this implicitly means that the whole test is inside that synchronized block, this effectively means that nothing on that test can be executed in parallel; then it's better just to categorize your tests and ensure that "xml dependant" tests are executed in sequence (while the rest still can be executed in parallel).

Regarding maven question, everything should be all right no matter what it does. If same process your lock will ensure nothing breaks; if different processes, the tests are completely isolated.